# Why upload something when I open Gmail?

Tags: google-chrome, upload, gmail

I can't understand why it uploads something when I open GMAIL in Chrome Browser.

You can see how it was uploaded in the image below.

Is anything being stolen from my computer?

Is there an option if I want to stop it?

Is it working against security?

Or I should let what is happening happen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but in my opinion, it will upload some information about your google account and computer information(physical address, IP address, location).

You can check other websites to check what happens in the beginning.